# How to show search marker with title and hide others marker android map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

i retrieve several marker from database using json and php , Now i want to search marker by title and show that marker with title and hide other marker.
here is java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();



    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fragment.getMap();
        //  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        new RetrieveTask().execute();

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user changed the Text
                showMarker(s.toString());
            }


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub    

            }

    });
    }

private void showMarker(String s) {

        for (Marker marker : markers) {

            if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }   




    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.43.229/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);

       }
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    String name;
    LatLng latLng;
    double lat;
    double lng;

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = result.get(i);
                lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                name = hmPlace.get("name");
                String locality = hmPlace.get("locality");
                String city = hmPlace.get("city");
                latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.snippet(locality + "," + city);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.school_marker));
                markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(24.66372, 93.90627), 8.0f));
            }
        }
    }
```

here is xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="Search Here" />
 <fragment  
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a `List<Marker>` to hold your markers (I'm using a `List` instead of a `Map` because you need to iterate over all your markers to hide all of them but one):

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, instead of adding your markers to the map doing `googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` you will need to add them like this to also add them to the `List<Marker>`:

```
markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
```

Now you can hide all your markers except the one with the desired title:

```
private void showMarker(String title) {
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fragment.getMap();
        //  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }

    private void showMarker(String title) {
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.43.229/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    String name;
    LatLng latLng;
    double lat;
    double lng;

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = result.get(i);
                lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                name = hmPlace.get("name");
                String locality = hmPlace.get("locality");
                String city = hmPlace.get("city");
                latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.snippet(locality + "," + city);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.school_marker));
                markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(24.66372, 93.90627), 8.0f));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to call `showMarker` with the desired title to hide (but not remove) all markers except the desired one.

Comment: i dont understand how to do please help me with my code

Comment: pls tell me how to search and show marker using edittext

Comment: To increase the visibility of your question so other people can answer and maybe help others with the same problem you should ask a new question (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions)

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Marker YourMarker;
//Your code

YourMarker=googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
YourMarker.showInfoWindow();
```